# Should the sign in/out/sign up pages be a part of the UsersController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

What are peoples opinions on if the UsersController should be possessing the login, singup, logout pages or should some other controller be taking this part. I'm just wondering, because I could do both. I could do this inside the UsersController cause the users log in, and well they somehow relate. Or I could make named pre-pass or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldnt take it into the users controller..

make a new session controller, which has also new/destroy actions.. then its more restful..

Comment: If you were using a gem for authentication? Like Authlogic?

Comment: why not? its common use to seperate the login procedure into a sessions controller

Comment: See http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1?view=asciicast or http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch?view=asciicast

Comment: im happy that i could help you

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I prefer gems helping me, I guess I'm a little lazy :(

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is have a `UserSessionsController` with restful actions. Then in my routes, something like this:

```
get '/login' => 'user_sessions#new'
post '/login' => 'user_sessions#create'
get '/logout' => 'user_sessions#destroy' # or delete '/logout'
```

I put registration stuff in a `RegistrationsController`.

If I need user management in an admin section, for example, I have an `Admin::UsersController` (or just a `UsersController`).

Comment: What if you are using a gem, like AuthLogic? Would you then also use a
UserSessionsController or would you just stick to a UsersController?

Comment: I usually use this with the sorcery gem, but sure, it'll work with AuthLogic. Yes, I would use a UserSessionsController. AuthLogic's documentation has an example of this. https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic Devise is a lot more opinionated, but the structure is similar to this.

Comment: Great! Super! Then I'll do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

i think, it is common to do this inside the UsersController.

Comment: mhm, maybe, I kinda felt that the UsersController was more like controlling the users, and not the login stuff and such. :S